# SW Versioning: Will it impact SmartCVS if we change software version to 5 digits?

Tags: version-control

For now our software follow standard version numbering with 4 digits. There is a request to add another digit (eg. v1.1.1.1.1). Will be any impact to SmartCVS or SmartGit if software version does not follow standard versioning?